# Install tool from source on pythonanywhere

Tags: python, linux, bioinformatics, pythonanywhere

I am trying to use Pythonanywhere to run some of my scripts. Eventually I would like to turn the entire code into a webapp, but I am not there yet.
Anyway, I would like to install a couple of bioinformatics packages on Pythonanywhere. Biopython has wrappers for these tools, but you still need the actual tools instaled. The tools in question do not have pip or easyinstall compatibility. So I think I will have to download/compile from source? However, I keep on running into "no permission" issues. Would a virtualenv be a solution?

As always, any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: using `sudo` doesn't solve?

Comment: no, I do not think sudo works on pythonanywhere.

Comment: Hi Stylize, PythonAnywhere dev here. If you send us an email / submit feedback about what packages you want to install, we can put it into the build for you so that it comes installed! Virtualenvs only work for python based stuff. We do have gcc and a couple other compilers available, so you could also investigate compiling from source (but will have to be careful to make sure the stuff you compile/install installs into your homedir and not into a global location that you do not have permissions to chg)

Answer (score 1):

Virtualenv works for Python packages.

However if you're trying to use non Python packages/libraries it won't be of much use.

Since the tools don't have easyinstall or pip compatibility I don't think using virtualenv will work out.

Download and compile from source should work though.

Note that if Biopython is installable via easyinstall or pip then use virtualenv to get that.